# Create unique node with many relationships in one cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have set of nodes with property "x". I want to create node with property "y" and make relationships to "x" nodes in one query. I made this query:

```
MATCH (x) WHERE has(x.x) CREATE (y{y:"y"}), (y)-[:REL]->(x);
```

This makes two nodes "y" and each of them have one relationship to "x", but I want one node "y" and from this node two relationships to every "x" node.

Comment: Have you tried using `MERGE` for your y node, something like `MERGE (y{y:"y"}) CREATE y-[:REL]->x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved

```
MATCH (x) WHERE HAS (x.x) MERGE (y { y:"y" }) CREATE (y)-[:REL]->(x);
```